# Why are the brackets and commas so strangely placed in "function name([param[, param[, ... param]]])"?

Tags: javascript

I've always seen this, but I've never understood. Why do so many functions have these nested brackets and oddly placed commas in the function definitions?

Something like

```
function name(param, param param)
```

would make sense to me, or

```
function name([param, [param, [param, [param]]]])
```

would make sense, but what's the reason for having the left bracket to the left of a comma?

Comment: That’s only for documentation, I guess. Every bracketed word or group of words means it’s optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the argument is optional. For example, in

```
function foo(par1[, par2]) {}
```

the `par1` argument is mandatory, but the `par2` is optional. In case you use the `par2`, then the comma is needed, so that's why it is included in the braces.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!